# iOS SideMenu crashing when trying to open in another storyboard

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiviewcontroller

I have little experience with iOS and Swift and I'm trying to create a SlideOut menu, or NavigationDrawer as it is called on Android.
So far I'm using this [library](https://github.com/jonkykong/SideMenu) (SideMenu by JonkyKong) because it's easily customizable and as described in the Read-Me on GitHub, it can be used globally on all the screens.

This is my problem: On my menu `tableViewController` I have two `storyboard segues`, one to the main storyboard, and one to the second storyboard. If I switch to the second storyboard, when I try to open the menu, the application crashes with the following error: `Application tried to present modally an active controller`.

### The menu setup I did as following

In my AppDelegate.swift file, on the `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` function I wrote this:

```
 var window: UIWindow?

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    // I've placed the menu ViewController on it's own storyboard, so I load it here to be used in the next line
    let navDrawerStoryBoard = UIStoryboard.init(name: "NavDrawer", bundle: nil)

    // Loads the menu
    SideMenuManager.menuLeftNavigationController = navDrawerStoryBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "LeftMenuNavigationController") as? UISideMenuNavigationController

    // Here I'm setting a gesture recognizer to show the menu
    SideMenuManager.menuAddScreenEdgePanGesturesToPresent(toView: window!)

    return true

}
```

I also uploaded my project to GitHub in case anyone needs it: [sideMenuTest](https://github.com/faelmorais/sideMenuTest)

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting that main exception because you are presenting your second view modally over an already open menu.

SideMenu shares one menu instance across all views, so if the menu is already open below the modal second view, opening it again results in the exception you see.

The solution to the above is to use the "Show" segue kind in storyboard instead of the modal one:
[image: Show instead of modal]

After doing show, however, you also need to embed your initial view in a NavigationController:
[image: Embed in nav]

Next, assuming you want it to keep looking the same, hide the navigation bar:
[image]

Lastly*, if you want to allow navigation back to the first screen smoothly, you will want to skip the navigation controller when pushing. In your NavDrawer storyboard, add an ID to the storyboard reference:
[image]

And add the same id as the Storyboard ID of the appropriate controller:
[image]

* *In my testing, I had to delete the segue to the first screen and recreate it for it to work.*

Comment: Thank you very much Eric! It worked flawless. +1 for the prints on the answer :)

Comment: How to close the open side menu on a button tap?

Answer (score 0):

try adding

```
//this should be the view controller you want to show
self.window?.rootViewController = SideMenuManager.menuLeftNavigationController
self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

and better add gestures in `viewDidLoad` of `ViewController`

Comment: How to close the open side menu on a button tap?

Comment: I moved and using this [one](https://github.com/nathantannar4/SwiftMiniProjects/tree/master/UIDrawerController).

Answer (score 0):

Try embedding each of the view Controller into a Navigation View Controller.

[Embed in Navigation View Controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nMB6J.jpg)